# Unable to install ros2 in ubuntu 23.10

Tags: ros2

**unable to install Ros 2 in ubuntu 23.10 because of unable to release file please suggest me**

Answer (score 0):

According to [REP2000](https://www.ros.org/reps/rep-2000.html) there is no installation candidate for Ubuntu 23.10.

May you have to switch your distribution or compile the source code of ROS2.

Acording to [this answer](https://answers.ros.org/question/415326/ros2-ubuntu-23/) from gvdhoorn, there are no plans to support ROS2 on Ubuntu 23.x